# Jquery, working with audio

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have a list of songs, when I click on particular link song should be changed.
Ok, song was changed, but it does not play anymore. Any ideas?

```
<div id="music">
    <a href="horse.mp3">horse music</a>
    <a href="eminem.mp3">Eminem song</a>
</div>
<audio controls>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

and

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#music a').click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            var value = $(this).attr('href');
            $('p').html("<p>"+value+"</p>");
            $('source').attr("src", value);
            audio.load(); 

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is `audio` is defined ???

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: it plays the first song, but does not play another,when i'm changing (it stil plays first song and that is all)

Comment: `audio.load(); `..... in this line `audio` is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#music a').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var audioElement = $("audio");
        var value = $(this).attr('href');
        $('p').html("<p>"+value+"</p>");
        audioElement.attr('src', value);
        audioElement.trigger('play');
    });
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#music a').click(function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var value = $(this).attr('href');
            $('p').html("<p>"+value+"</p>");
            $('source').attr("src", value);
            var audio = $('audio');
            audio.attr('src', value);
            audio.load();
            audio.trigger('play');
        });
    });
```